# Program stuck when using parallel for

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.for

I'm fairly new to C# and I made a simple program simmulating lotto draws. It takes first (random) numbers and calculates how many draws it takes to win. It's a polish lotto, so there are 6 numbers to match.

Everything works fine, when program is run in simple for loop. But there is a problem, when I use Parallel For or whatever other multitasking or multithreding option.

First the code:

```
class Program
{
    public static int howMany = 100;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Six my;
        Six computers;
        long sum = 0;
        double avg = 0;
        int min = 1000000000;
        int max = 0;



        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
        {
            my = new Six();
            Console.WriteLine((i + 1).ToString() + " My: " + my.ToString());

            int counter = 0;
            do
            {
                computers = new Six();
                counter++;
            } while (!my.Equals(computers));
            Console.WriteLine((i + 1).ToString() + " Computers: " + computers.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(counter.ToString("After: ### ### ###") + "\n");
            if (counter < min)
                min = counter;
            if (counter > max)
                max = counter;
            sum += counter;
        }

        avg = sum / howMany;
        Console.WriteLine("Average: " + avg);
        Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + sum);
        Console.WriteLine("Min: " + min);
        Console.WriteLine("Max: " + max);

        Console.Read();
    }

}







class Six : IEquatable<Six>
{
    internal byte first;
    internal byte second;
    internal byte third;
    internal byte fourth;
    internal byte fifth;
    internal byte sixth;
    private static Random r = new Random();

    public Six()
    {

        GenerateRandomNumbers();
    }

    public bool Equals(Six other)
    {
        if (this.first == other.first
            && this.second == other.second
            && this.third == other.third
            && this.fourth == other.fourth
            && this.fifth == other.fifth
            && this.sixth == other.sixth)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private void GenerateRandomNumbers()
    {
        byte[] numbers = new byte[6];
        byte k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                k = (byte)(r.Next(49) + 1);
            }while (numbers.Contains(k));

            numbers[i] = k;
            k = 0;
        }

        Array.Sort(numbers);

        this.first = numbers[0];
        this.second = numbers[1];
        this.third = numbers[2];
        this.fourth = numbers[3];
        this.fifth = numbers[4];
        this.sixth = numbers[5];
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.first + ", " + this.second + ", " + this.third + ", " + this.fourth + ", " + this.fifth + ", " + this.sixth;
    }

}
```

And when I try to make it Parallel.For:

```
        long sum = 0;
        double avg = 0;
        int min = 1000000000;
        int max = 0;


        Parallel.For(0, howMany, (i) =>
        {
            Six my = new Six();
            Six computers;
            Console.WriteLine((i + 1).ToString() + " My: " + my.ToString());

            int counter = 0;
            do
            {
                computers = new Six();

                // Checking when it's getting stuck
                if (counter % 100 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine(counter);

                counter++;
            } while (!my.Equals(computers));
            Console.WriteLine((i + 1).ToString() + " Computers: " + computers.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(counter.ToString("After: ### ### ###") + "\n");

            // It never get to this point, so there is no problem with "global" veriables
            if (counter < min)
                min = counter;
            if (counter > max)
                max = counter;
            sum += counter;
        });
```

Program gets stuck at some point. Counters get to ~3,000-40,000 and refuses to go further.

What I tried:

1. Making class a struct
2. Collecting Garbage every ~1000 iterations
3. Using ThreadPool
4. Using Task.Run
5. Making random class Program member only (tired to make Six class "lighter")

But I got nothing.

I know that this might be a very simple thing for some of you, but man got to learn somehow ;) I even bought a book about async programming to find out why doesn't it work, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: We are lacking too much information. On what line is it getting stuck? Are you classes thread-safe?

Comment: There is a comment in the code that indicates when it's getting stuck. it's stuck on do..while loop. And no - what you see is the whole code..

Comment: And how can I make a breakpoint so that I know when it's stuck? I cant click continue 40 000 times, and I don't know when it's going to stuck so can't make breakpoint conditional.

Comment: Breakpoints, don't always help with multi-threaded locking issues. You change the behaving when you breakpoint the code.

Comment: Well that's just another reason why I can't really tell what line exactly is it stuck at. But it's definetely between do and while, cause the Console.WriteLine("Computers: ") never executes...

Comment: When generating random numbers without replacement, it is better to put the possible numbers in a list and randomly pick one removing it, especially when the amount is small. This way you never will run into an eternal loop, though this code would still always have the same numbers drawn.

Comment: @JamesBarrass you're right.. I don't know why I've said that. Seem logic for some reason. disregard my comment.  Ill erase it because it doesnt bring anything on table more than confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`Random` isn't thread safe...

Wait for your code to stop writing new lines in the parallel version and the pause. This stops all threads. You'll notice that all your parallel threads are in the while loop.

The numbers array's are all 1,0,0,0,0,0 and r.Next only returns 1. which the byte array always contains. So, you broke `Random`

To fix this you'll need to make r thread safe, either by locking r every time you access r.Next or changing the static declaration to

```
private static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> r
     = new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random());
```

and the `Next` call becomes

```
k = (byte)(r.Value.Next(49) + 1);
```

This will create a new static Random instance per thread.

As you noted, creating lots of Random's at the same time result the in same sequence of numbers being produced, to get around this add a seed class

```
static class RGen
{
    private static Random seedGen = new Random();

    public static Random GetRGenerator()
    {
        lock (seedGen)
        {
            return new Random(seedGen.Next());
        }
    }
}
```

and change the declaration to

```
private static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> r
     = new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => RGen.GetRGenerator());
```

This will ensure each new random instance has a different seed value.

Comment: Well it worked partially - numbers on first for loops (for every thread) are the same, program workes fine afterwards.
Besides - random won't work even if every Six has it's own Random r field?

Comment: They will be, Each `new Random()` reseeds the generator from the system clock. If they're created too close together they start at the same seed. You'd have to write a bit more code to get around that, or use lock statements so you only have a single instance of `Random`

Comment: If randomness is a concern, use the [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) which is thread-safe

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on what James Barrass wrote:

```
public static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> r = new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + DateTime.Now.Miliseconds));
```

That made program running well :)

Comment: careful with that. The ManagedThreadId can be recycled and if that happens you'll generate the same sequence of random numbers as previously in that thread.

Comment: Well I get random numbers but every time I run program the numbers are the same as previously. But without it there are iterations where couple of threads return same "my" numbers so it's not ideal either. Any idea how to get different random numbers in each thread each time I run program?

Comment: See my edit which uses seed generator to get a new seed for each thread